# How to pass function as a parameter while navigating to another page through router.navigate.?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I’m converting ionic-3 code to ionic-4 and not able to call function of previous page to current page. In ionic-3 function was send as a parameter and at another page I get it through navparams, but in ionic-4 navparams are removed.

In ionic-3, page was push like this and function as a parameter passes like this :

```js
getProductDetail(event:any, productObject : any) {
    this.currentPage = this.navCtrl.getActive().name;
    this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push('ProductDetail', {
       callback : this.updateProductCallback,
       id :productObject
    });
}
```

This is how I get function passed as a callback to Product Detail page and call it again.

```js
this.callback = this.navParam.get("callback");
if(self.callback) {
    self.callback(self.changeProductType).then(()=>{
        self.navCtrl.pop();
    });
}
```

How to pass and get this callback function in ionic -4.

Comment: I would recommend doing the same now using a shared service (basically have both of your pages to share a singleton service that contains the method). Let me know if you need help implementing it, but it should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thank you so much Sergey for answering my question. 
But there are 50+ pages in my application and each page have callback functionality with navigation to other three pages. So its's not possible for creating singleton service for each page.

Please let me know if you find out any other solution for it.